# What does <T?> mean in Class declaration?

Tags: c#, generics

`class MyClass<T>` is a generic class. But what is `class MyClass<T?>` ?
I'm only guessing it defines T as nullable type ? But if its so I don't understand how and why.
Can't find anything about it on web.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at C# code? That doesn't compile.

Comment: That's a syntax error

Comment: its just a `Syntax Error`!

Comment: `class MyClass<T?>` will always be a syntax error. You could have a `?` in a generic type, but not in its definition. This is completely legal: `List<T?> Test<T>() where T : struct { return new List<T?>(); }`

Comment: I have encountered it in 'Extended WPF Toolkit'. Specifically in NumericUpDown class. Since the lib is written in c# and it does compile (I tried) I thought its some syntax I didn't know. -- Maybe it's something custom defined by the authors ?

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko - the duplicate you sugested is wrong. I am not asking about nullable types. That is something very different then generics.

Comment: No, you've misread. There is no `class MyClass<T?>`. There's `class MyClass<T> : OtherClass<T?> where T : struct`, which is perfectly legal. In other words, you can make a `class NullableList<T> : List<T?> where T : struct` which is a list that only takes nullables.

Comment: @Luaan - Yes, you are right. Thanks for explanation -- Can you make it an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you've misread. There is no `class MyClass<T?>`.

There's `class MyClass<T> : OtherClass<T?> where T : struct`, which is perfectly legal.

In other words, you can do this:

```
class NullableList<T> : List<T?> where T : struct {}
```

And you'll get a generic list, which uses a nullable type as its generic type, eg. if you create a `NullableList<int>`, it will have a method `Add(int? val)`.

Funnily enough, through the syntactic sugar magic of nullables, you can't have a Nullable of a Nullable (eg. `Nullable<Nullable<int>>` for example), even though `Nullable<T>` is a struct. It produces a compile-time error.

Comment: Again, thanks for correction and explanation !